# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target.name')

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo

So im trying to make an authentication with react native and graphql apollo and im having some issues with it. This error pops up when i try typing on the name textinput.

***SignIn.js***

```
// ... other imports
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { useForm } from '../constants/hooks';

const { onChange, onSubmit, values } = useForm(loginUserCallback, {
    name: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const [loginUser, { loading }] = useMutation(mutationData.LOGIN_USER, {
    update(_, { data: { login: userData } }) {
      // context.login(userData);
      navigation.replace('Navigator'); // router.push("/");
      // toast.success(`Logged In Successfully`, { autoClose: 800 });
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.errors);
    },
    variables: values,
  });

  function loginUserCallback() {
    loginUser();
  }

return (
  <View>
    <TextInput
      value={values.name}
      name="name"
      onChangeText={onChange}
      placeholder="Enter User Name"
    />
    <TextInput
      value={values.password}
      name="password"
      onChangeText={onChange}
      placeholder="Enter Password"
    />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
      <Text>SIGN IN</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

***hooks.js***

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useForm = (callback, initialState = {}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    callback();
  };

  return {
    onChange,
    onSubmit,
    values,
  };
};
```

***mutationData.js***

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

// =============
// Auth
// =============

const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation login($name: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(name: $name, password: $password) {
      id
      email
      username
      createdAt
      token
    }
  }
`;

const REGISTER_USER = gql`
  mutation register(
    $username: String!
    $email: String!
    $password: String!
    $confirmPassword: String!
  ) {
    register(
      registerInput: {
        username: $username
        email: $email
        password: $password
        confirmPassword: $confirmPassword
      }
    ) {
      id
      email
      username
      createdAt
      token
    }
  }
`;

export default {
  LOGIN_USER,
  REGISTER_USER,
};
```

Extra Info:

- Im using expo for react native.
- All Imports have no issues.
- All Packages i have installed have no problems.
- CODESANDBOX LINK: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sound-boctx5?file=/src/SignIn.js

If i miss any details, which i know this is an uninformative post, pls tell in the comments and ill try my best to provide those information, also yes i tried working on the error for a few hours.

Comment: You need to share the code of the `TextInput` component. I think that the problem lies there

Comment: The TextInput Component is in react native itself though? i didn't create that as a custom component.

Comment: Pls check the edited post, i added codesandbox link so that you can try to edit some things and maybe fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I've figured out your problem

One problem is that `onChangeText` as @Appfred pointed out returns the value not the event

the second problem is that `TextInput` doesn't have a name props so it ignore the one you are passing

you can resolve your problem with a few adjustments.

in your custom hook you need to change the `onChange` signature like this

```
  const onChange = (name, value) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };
```

and you need to modify your form in this way

```
<View>
    <TextInput
      value={values.name}
      onChangeText={value => onChange('name', value)}
      placeholder="Enter User Name"
    />
    <TextInput
      value={values.password}
      onChangeText={value => onChange('password', value)}
      placeholder="Enter Password"
    />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
      <Text>SIGN IN</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

or if you preferer a curried function approach you could do

```
  const onChange = name => value => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };
```

and then

```
<View>
    <TextInput
      value={values.name}
      onChangeText={ onChange('name') }
      placeholder="Enter User Name"
    />
    <TextInput
      value={values.password}
      onChangeText={ onChange('password') }
      placeholder="Enter Password"
    />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSubmit}>
      <Text>SIGN IN</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to React Native's documentation on the onChangeText function for [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext):

> Changed text is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler.

Thus, `event` is the string, `event.target` is undefined, and when trying get `event.target.name` you get this error. To grab the target and name, use the [onChange](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange) function instead, with `event` swapped out for `nativeEvent`.

Comment: so i will change onChangeText to onChange and change event to nativeEvent? brb. 
Edit: ok so apparently when I type in the textinput now, it deletes the text when I'm typing.

Comment: As I understand, you need to pass the string as a return value, otherwise the callback will be empty, therefore emptying the string as you type. Something like ``(event) => { return event }`` should work wih the ``onChangeText`` function

Comment: it still has the same problem sadly.

Comment: Pls check the edited post, i added codesandbox link so that you can try to edit some things and maybe fix the problem.